# How can pst-optexp be used to draw a solar panel hit by wide beam?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, pstricks, pst-node, pst-optic

I would like to make the following diagram:

[image]

Now, I know it is possible to make a box with the laser, and the spectroradiameter, and even then wide-beam, using the gradient I am sure, but I am not sure if it is possible to draw a solar panel.

Is it possible to make a solar panel using this library? It doesn't have to be perfect, but I am not sure an optbox will make it justice.

Thank you.

Comment: What you want is not quite clear. Must your solar panel be  a grey rectangle, as in the above image?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback. I was trying to be a simple as possible to communicate the idea. I am curious if it is possible to use this library to make something closer to what a solar panel would be.

Comment: I don't think so, according to the documentation, but I guess it can be done with the general `pstricks` package 'and probably `pst-node`). However, I have no idea what the standard representation of solar panels is.

Answer (score 4):

If you want just draw a solar panel for a graphic you can just use simple Tikz:

A suggestion of how I would represent a solar panel:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.07, 0.04, 0.56}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,1,2}
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3}
        \foreach \a in {1,2}
        \foreach \b in {1,2,3}
    {
        \draw[color=lightgray,very thick,fill=darkblue] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+1,\y+1);
        \fill[lightgray] (\a,\b) circle (0.1cm);
    }
        \foreach \x in  {0.25,0.5,0.75,...,3} {%
        \draw[thin, lightgray] (\x,0) -- (\x,4);

    }
\end{tikzpicture}
    
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

The rest of the graph:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.07, 0.04, 0.56}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
% see pgf manual
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{rainbow}{100bp}{color(0bp)=(red);color(25bp)=(red);color(35bp)=(yellow);color(45bp)=(green);color(55bp)=(cyan);color(65bp)=(blue);color(75bp)=(violet);color(100bp)=(violet)}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    %laser
    %\draw[color=cyan,fill=cyan] (-7,2.5) rectangle (-5,1.5) node[midway,black]{Laser};
    
    
    %pretty laser
    \shade[ball color=green!40!white] (-10,2) ellipse (2cm and 1cm) node[yshift=-2cm] {\huge Laser};
    \shade[ball color=red!40!white] (-8,1.9) rectangle (-5,2.1);
    \foreach \x in {-8,-8.3,-8.6}
    \shade[ball color=red!40!white] (\x,2) ellipse (0.25cm and 1cm);
    \shade[ball color=red!40!white] (-5,2) circle (0.5cm);
    
    
    %beam
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg} 
    \shade[shading=rainbow] (-4.6,2) -- (0,1.5) -- (0,2.5);
    \end{pgfonlayer}


    %solar panel
        \foreach \x in {0,1,2}
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3}
        \foreach \a in {1,2}
        \foreach \b in {1,2,3}
    {
        \draw[color=lightgray,very thick,fill=darkblue] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+1,\y+1);
        \fill[lightgray] (\a,\b) circle (0.1cm);
    }
        \foreach \x in  {0.25,0.5,0.75,...,3} {%
        \draw[thin, lightgray] (\x,0) -- (\x,4);

    }

    %spectrometer
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg} 
    \draw[color=magenta!20!white,fill=magenta!20!white] (3.75,2.5) rectangle (6.25,1.5) node[midway,black, minimum size=3cm]{spectrometer};
    \draw [very thick,color=magenta!20!white] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (3,2) (3.4,3) (3.6,1.5) (4,2)};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    
\end{tikzpicture}   
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, pretty laser indeed ;-P